# @Input not updating in child component when changed in parent

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic-framework

I have two components set up, the parent, `pvp` and the child, `battle-arrowhead`, I'm trying to maintain an updated document in `pvp` that `battle-arrowhead` can access using an @Input. I want to do this using Observables by having `pvp` subscribe to a firebase document change stream and update its document on each change, which will then be reflected in the child. However, I'm not seeing changes reflected in `battle-arrowhead` when I update the document in `pvp`. Here are the important parts of the code I have now:

pvp.component.html:

```
  <app-battle-arrowhead
    *ngIf="inArrowhead"
    [matchDocument]="matchDocument"
    (arrowheadPlacedEvent)="changeToTransition()"
  ></app-battle-arrowhead>
```

pvp.component.ts:

```
  setMatchDocument(document) {
    this.matchDocument = document;
    this.api
      .getMatchValueChangesObservable(document.id)
      .subscribe(this.onDocumentChange);
  }

  onDocumentChange(docChange) {
    this.matchDocument = docChange;
    console.log('changing match doc to ', JSON.stringify(this.matchDocument));
  }
```

Here, setMatchDocument is called by an event when a match is found in a separate matchmaking component.

```
battle-arrowhead.component.ts:

  @Input() matchDocument = 0;

  test() {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(this.matchDocument));
  }
```

I am testing this by making a change in firebase, where I then see a console.log message from pvp.component.ts, saying it is changing the match document to the updated version. Then, within the arrowhead component, I have a button that simply calls test(), and this prints the old version of the document, rather than the updated version.

I am following this guide:

https://angular.io/guide/inputs-outputs

And I have matched things closely. I have tried also making a copy of the document and setting it to this copy to try to trigger updates, but this has not worked. Am I misunderstanding how @input works? I'm new to angular and ionic, so any advice is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Did you tried ngonchanges() life cycle hook? It may solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

What type is `matchDocument`? Most of the code suggests it's an `object`, but your arrowhead component suggests it's a `number`.

That inconsistency aside, it's probably not the issue (though seriously, TS is a typed language, so make use of it to aid with context within your code).

It *looks* like things are suitably hooked up to work - no, you probably haven't misunderstood how inputs work; so long as the whole of the object `matchDocument` is updated, Angular will detect the change (vs only a value within it).

There's the possibility that you're not changing objects; presumably the underlying services that provide the document are providing the same document. However, you say you've attempted to copy the object (e.g. something like `this.matchDocument = {...this.matchDocument};` perhaps?) so maybe it's not that, though it does feel like it.

One thing you can do, which I've found helpful in debugging issues like these, to figure out where and when thing are happening and coming into my components: split it up into `get` and `set`.

E.g.

```js
private _matchDocument: any;

@Input() public set matchDocument(val: any) {
    console.log('setting matchDocument to: ', val);
    this._matchDocument = val;
}

public get matchDocument(): any { return this._matchDocument; }
```

That enables you to hook in to any setting of `matchDocument` and see when it's happening and what value is being set every time it happens, so that you can ensure that it *does* happen.

It's not an answer, but a helpful thing to do sometimes if you want to see what's going on.